# Notify a Collection View Cell to changes its subviews using NotificationCenter - swift

Tags: ios, swift

is this a good thing? observing for notifications and changing values in collection view cell without reload all collection view cells?

**i know i can reload a cell like this**

```
collectionView.reloadCell(at....)
```

**but this is not the case, i want cells to update their subviews independently, not using collection view**

i have a collection view, it has one or more cells, each cell has a label that shows how many of this item is currently in Shopping cart, so when user add something to the cart, my collection view cell has to changes its count label text

i observe for a notification, then check the id of added item with my cell item id, if it is equal then cell has to changes count label value
[the numbers are look like this numbers above each item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xztaQ.png)

i can give another example, say we have some cells, each cell starts loading 10 images, every time an image downloaded, cells have to change their downloaded count label so user can see how many imaged downloaded,

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not a good idea. You want your cells to reflect the state of the model that they display. If the model changes, you need to notify the table view that it needs to update it's cells.

You can implement logic that only reloads the specific cells that have changed. (using the method `reloadRows(at:with:)`)

Comment: but i want to change just a number not whole cell, user can see this cell reload completely with reloadRows(at:with:)

Comment: its not possible to reload particular subview alone

Comment: if my cell realizes somethings is changed, it can updates that label like lbl_count.text = "12"

Comment: No. **Do not** have your CELL worry about changes. A cell should now have knowledge of the model that feeds it. That is the job of the table view's data source.

Comment: Trust me, what you are talking about is a very bad idea. Don't go there.

Comment: BTW, I realized that you asked about collection views, and I answered about table views. The same answer applies equally to both types.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by reloading that particular cell of the collectionView. I hope you are using the async Images for the product listed.

```
let row = YOUR RESULTED ROW VALUE, UPDATE IT 
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

Achieving it by Notification is not a good idea, above solution is good approach.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggest, it's better to change model and then reload the cell.
But actually you can access a particular cell of the collection view by doing

`collectionView.cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)`

And then you can cast the returned `UICollectionViewCell` to your custom cell and access subviews of that cell.

**Important**: This methods returns `nil` if that cell is not visible!

Answer (score 0):

I am not cool with **cell update animation** for this situation, so I was looking for a way to let this responsibility to my cells, so they could change their subviews independently,
but you all guys told me using that option, so I was looking for something to stop cell update animation, I mean I don't want my user notice that whole cell updated(fade...) so I come with this solution

```
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        // Update UI that you don't want to animate

       self.collectionView.cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)
    }
```

now I notify my collection view, check if that item is currently showing on the screen, then reload that index without animation

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look through the visible cells and change them accordingly.

1- Change your values in the datasource

2- Look for the changed cells using the tableView's `visibleCells` property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells.

3- Call a method in the cell that would change the value/number

Obviously if the cell isn't visible, it will be changed the next time it becomes visible. Just make sure to keep your datasource up to date (whether it's a model or a cell view model)